# Object Doesn't support this method

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am getting a

> Object doesn't support this method

when I click the start button. It says the line is;

```
<input type="button" name="btnStart" id="btnStart" value="Start" onclick="Start_Button">
```

I believe it actually may be somewhere in my vbscript. When I click on the start button it depending on whether the `strPath` is entered and the checkbox is checked it should run the program to install, or tell me that I need to enter the `strPath` or check a box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Tombstone USD #1 - Software Installer</title>

    <HTA:APPLICATION
        APPLICATIONNAME = "Software Installer"
        ICON = "images\districtlogo.ico"
        ID = "NAME"
        BORDER = "thick"        
        CAPTION = "yes"
        SHOWINTASKBAR = "yes"
        SINGLEINSTANCE = "yes"
        SYSMENU = "yes"
        WINDOWSTATE="normal"
        SCROLL = "no"
        VERSION = "1.0"
        INNERBORDER = "yes"
        SELECTION = "yes"
        MAXIMIZEBUTTON = "no"
        MINIMIZEBUTTON = "no"
        NAVIGABLE = "no"
        CONTEXTMENU = "yes"
        BORDERSTYLE = "normal"
    />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--Resolution//-->
        window.resizeTo(600,750);
    </script>

    <script language="VBScript">
        Sub Start_Button()

            Dim strAnswer,strPath, objNetwork
            Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
            strAnswer = ""
            strPath=""

            If chkEset.Checked Then strAnswer = "Eset"

            'If strPath is empty then nothing was checked.
            If strPath = "" Then 
                Window.Alert "Please input Path location!"
            End If

            'If strAnswer is empty then nothing was checked.
            If strAnswer = "" Then 
                Window.Alert "Please Make an Selection!"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Window.Alert "Done!"
        End Sub
    </script>   

</head>

<body style="background-color:#E6E6FA">
    <center>
        <img src="images\districtlogo.png" alt="Logo" height="100" width="100"/>
        <h1>Software Installer</h1>
    </center>

    <form name="MainMenu" action="" method="">
        <label for="sPath">Drive Letter or File Path:</label><input type="text" size="60" id="sPath" name="sPath"></td>
        <br />
        <label for="Eset">ESet AntiVirus</label></td><input type="checkbox" id="Eset" name="chkEset">
        <br />
        <input type="button" name="btnStart" id="btnStart" value="Start" onclick="Start_Button"> 
        <br />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm currently just trying to get this run with the one program. This is a proof of concept test.

Comment: `Set` is for object references which string variables aren't. Remove `Set` from `Set strAnswer = ""` and `Set strPath=""`.

Comment: I've tried it that way and still get the same thing.

Comment: Regardless, that would also break. If you want to know what is causing that particular error posting the line it occurs on would help, we are not mind readers.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had, its the line with start button. `<input type="button" name="btnStart" id="btnStart" value="Start" onclick="Start_Button"> `

Comment: Where are these values `chkNewInstall`, `chkWIN10UP` etc defined? They look like they are meant to be DOM elements probably checkboxes judging by the `checked` property but they aren’t even shown in the body of the HTA??

Comment: I removed them from the hta to lighten the reading of the code. Even with them I get the same thing. Tje above posted code was a simplified version as the original has tables and such.

Comment: Can you also [edit] the question and remove the code so it reflects what you’re testing please.

Comment: Also, don’t understand this line `If strAnswer = "Eset" Then Chr(34) & strPath & "\Programs\ESet Rip and Replace.exe" & Chr(34)` you never assign the string to a variable, that is never going to work and will error.

Comment: There updated the code. Lets get that to work first. I'm not over concerned with the  `If strAnswer = "Eset" Then Chr(34) & strPath & "\Programs\ESet Rip and Replace.exe" & Chr(34)` as its not the one causing the problem.

Comment: Wait, you know which line is causing the error?

Comment: No, but that line removed still causes the issue.

Comment: Here’s an idea, remove all the script lines from `Start_Button()` and add them back one at a time until you hit the error again, or better yet debug it. Good day.

Comment: From what I can gather is the button `<input type="button" name="btnStart" id="btnStart" value="Start" onclick="Start_Button">` doesn't see my `Sub Start_Button()`

Comment: All the debug does is show me the exact same error

Comment: So even if I take out all the scripting except the sub I get the samething.

Comment: That should work, sorry I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Ok that worked! Now I'm getting Line 75 `Object Required chkEset`. I did remove the `If chkEset.Checked Then strAnswer = "Eset"` and it asked me to fill in the path and make selection.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since I figured it out I thought I would add the completed script below. All this does is check to see if the `strPath` is filled in and if the checkbox is checked. Next step is to get it to run a program that corresponds to the checkbox.

The way I fixed it was by changing the `<input type="button" name="btnStart" id="btnStart" value="Start" onclick="Start_Button">` to `<input type="button" name="btnStart" id="btnStart" value="Start" onclick="Start_Button()">`.

I also realized that the Form wasn't actually assigning the values to the script and created `TheForm` value and assigned it to the `MainMenu` form. I then had to add that value to all the existing values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Tombstone USD #1 - Software Installer</title>

    <HTA:APPLICATION
        APPLICATIONNAME = "Software Installer"
        ICON = "images\districtlogo.ico"
        ID = "NAME"
        BORDER = "thick"        
        CAPTION = "yes"
        SHOWINTASKBAR = "yes"
        SINGLEINSTANCE = "yes"
        SYSMENU = "yes"
        WINDOWSTATE="normal"
        SCROLL = "no"
        VERSION = "1.0"
        INNERBORDER = "yes"
        SELECTION = "yes"
        MAXIMIZEBUTTON = "no"
        MINIMIZEBUTTON = "no"
        NAVIGABLE = "no"
        CONTEXTMENU = "yes"
        BORDERSTYLE = "normal"
    />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--Resolution//-->
        window.resizeTo(600,750);
    </script>

    <script language="VBScript">
        Sub Start_Button()

            Dim strAnswer,strPath, objNetwork,TheForm
            Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
            Set TheForm = Document.MainMenu
            strAnswer = ""
            strPath = ""

            If TheForm.chkEset.Checked Then strAnswer = "Eset"            

           'If strPath is empty then nothing was checked.
            If TheForm.strPath = "" Then 
                Window.Alert "Please input Path location!"
                Exit Sub            
            End If

            'If strAnswer is empty then nothing was checked.
            If strAnswer = "" Then 
                Window.Alert "Please Make an Selection!"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Window.Alert "Done!"
        End Sub
    </script>   

</head>

<body style="background-color:#E6E6FA">
    <center>
        <img src="images\districtlogo.png" alt="Logo" height="100" width="100"/>
        <h1>Software Installer</h1>
    </center>

    <form name="MainMenu" action="" method="">
        <label for="Path">Drive Letter or File Path:</label><input type="text" size="60" id="Path" name="strPath"></td>
        <br />
        <label for="Eset">ESet AntiVirus</label></td><input type="checkbox" id="Eset" name="chkEset">
        <br />
        <input type="button" name="btnStart" id="btnStart" value="Start" onclick="Start_Button()"> 
        <br />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```